# Changing the type of values in a list within a list

Tags: python, matrix, types, casting

I have the list

```
m = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9']]
```

I would like it to be like this

```
m1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

so that I can do some matrix calculations. I tried:

```
m1 = map(int, m)
```

but it didn't work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nested list, so a list comprehension would probably work best:

```
m1 = [[int(x) for x in row] for row in m]
```

Alternatively, if you would like to stick to `map`:

```
m1 = [list(map(int, row)) for row in m]
```